# Not able to click "Close" button of a Modal In Selenium Webdriver (Java)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

After clicking on a link a modal appear where a close button exist. I tried to close the modal with below code but it's not working.

```
WebElement element = driver1.findElement(By.className("btn btn-secondary"));

if (element.isEnabled()) {
  element.click();
} else {
  System.out.println("Disable");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running this in headful mode and see what happens?  Does it throw any error or warning?

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: You need to add the relevant HTML and error message.

Answer (score 1):

I can tell from your locator that you are at least getting the error,

> Compound class names not permitted

`By.className()` expects a single class name but you have provided two which will cause the error above. Without the HTML, it's hard to say what the best locator might be but one that might work is the CSS selector,

```
By.cssSelector(".btn.btn-secondary")
```

As generic as this is, it's possible that there is more than one element that matches.

You might need to add a wait, especially since you are dealing with a modal dialog,

```
new WebDriverWait(driver).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(...)).click();
```

You probably want another wait to make sure that the dialog closes before the script continues.